# For prime $p>2: 1^23^25^2\cdot\cdot\cdot(p-2)^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the square of all odds less than an odd prime $p$ congruent to $(-1)^{(p+1)/(2)}\pmod p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4827/why-is-the-square-of-all-odds-less-than-an-odd-prime-p-congruent-to-1p)
>   [If p is an odd prime, prove that $1^2 \times 3^2 \times 5^2 \cdots  \times (p-2)^2 \equiv (-1)^{(p+1)/2}\pmod{p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22399/if-p-is-an-odd-prime-prove-that-12-times-32-times-52-cdots-times-p-2)

I'd love your help with proving the following claim:

For prime $p>2$:

$$1^23^25^2\cdot\cdot\cdot(p-2)^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \pmod p.$$

I instantly thought of Wilson Theorem which says that $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(p-1) \equiv (-1) \pmod p$, but I can't see how to use it.

I also tried to divide it to two cases, for $p \equiv 1 \pmod4$, and $p \equiv 3 \pmod4$, but again I didn't reach the conclusion.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thats not Wilson's theorem. Check

Comment: On the right-hand side of the page your problem is on, [there is a link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22399/if-p-is-an-odd-prime-prove-that-1232-52-p-22-equiv-1p1-2?rq=1) to a solution of the same problem. The same problem also came up fairly recently. I think I was even one of the people who answered, but of course can't find a link to that.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Just curious. Why didn't you vote to close this question?

Comment: @Jozef: Note that for $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, this gives an explicit (though not computationally useful) formula for an $x$ such that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: @Marvis: I am generally not in favour of closing questions. My comment about the duplication was just meant to help the OP find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that

$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p$

Then, since $p-k\equiv -k \mod p$ we have

$$-1=(p-1)! =[1  \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot ... \cdot (p-2)] \cdot [ 2 \cdot 4 ... \cdot (p-1)]$$
$$=[1  \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot ... \cdot (p-2)] \cdot [ (p-2) \cdot (p-4) ... \cdot (1) \cdot (-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}] $$

Answer (score 2):

Since $p$ is odd, the negatives of the odd residues listed in your product are the even residues: $-1=p-1\pmod{p}$, $-3=p-3\pmod{p}$, $-5=p-5\pmod{p}$, etc.

By Wilson's Theorem, the product of all of these non-zero residues is $(p-1)!=-1\pmod{p}$.

Your product can be changed to $(p-1)!$ by
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00000}{1^2}\cdot\color{#00A000}{3^2}\cdot\color{#0000FF}{5^2}\cdots(p-2)^2
&=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\color{#C00000}{1\cdot(p-1)}\cdot\color{#00A000}{3\cdot(p-3)}\cdot\color{#0000FF}{5\cdot(p-5)}\cdots(p-2)\cdot2\\
&=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(-1)\\
&=(-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\pmod{p}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It isn't true. Take $p = 5$, then $1^2 3^2 \equiv -1 \not \equiv 1 \equiv (-1)^\frac{5-1}{2} \pmod 5$

Comment: Oh sorry, it's suppose to be $p+1$ in the power of $(-1)$. Any way please delete the answer so I could delete the question, since it has already been posted here.

Answer (score 1):

$$1^23^25^2\cdot\cdot\cdot(p-2)^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod p$$

is the same as

$$1^2 2^2 3^2 \cdots
\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2
\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod p,$$

since we are working modulo $p$.

Now we can split each square itself as $ i^2 = i(p-i)(-1) $

$$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} 123\cdot\cdot\cdot(p-1)\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \pmod p$$

from Wilson's theorem.