# What is $\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (2k-1)^2 \bmod p$ where $p$ is an odd prime?

Tags: factorial, congruences

What is
$\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (2k-1)^2
\bmod p$
where $p$ is an odd prime?

Note:
Someone just asked this
and it was deleted while
I was working on it,
so I am posting it
with my answer.

I get
$(-1)^{(p+1)/2}$.

Here is how.

Working mod $p$,

$\begin{array}\\
\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (2k-1)^2
&=\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (2k-1)^2\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (2k)^2}{\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (2k)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (k)^2}{2^{p-1}\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (k)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(p-1)!^2}{2^{p-1}((p-1)/2)!^2}\\
&\equiv \dfrac{1}{((p-1)/2)!^2}
\qquad\text{since }(p-1)! \equiv -1\text{ and }2^{p-1}\equiv 1\\
\end{array}
$

Also,

$\begin{array}\\
(p-1)!
&=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} k\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} k\prod_{k=(p+1)/2}^{p-1} k\\
&=((p-1)/2)!(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\prod_{k=(p+1)/2}^{p-1} (-k)\\
&\equiv((p-1)/2)!(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\prod_{k=(p+1)/2}^{p-1} (p-k)\\
&\equiv((p-1)/2)!(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} k\\
&\equiv((p-1)/2)!^2(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\\
\text{so}\\
-1
&\equiv ((p-1)/2)!^2(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\\
\text{or}\\
((p-1)/2)!^2
&\equiv -(-1)^{(p-1)/2}
\qquad\text{since } (-1)^{p-1} \equiv 1\\
&\equiv (-1)^{(p+1)/2}\\
\text{so that}\\
\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (2k-1)^2
&\equiv (-1)^{(p+1)/2}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164653/for-prime-p2-123252-cdot-cdot-cdotp-22-equiv-1-fracp12-pmo

Comment: At least I independently got the right answer. Thanks for the reference.